# Looking for a tool to generate bindingRedirect-s for .NET assemblies

Tags: .net

Say, my .NET project deployment directory looks like:

```
MyComponent.dll
MyComponent.dll.config
3rdPartyComponent.dll
3rdParty.dll.config
Newtonsoft.Json.dll (v7)
etc.
```

MyComponent.dll refers Newtonsoft.Json version 7 and 3rdPartyComponent.dll refers Newtonsoft.Json version 6. I'd like to catch this case and get a hint that bindingRedirect for Newtonsoft.Json assembly is needed in 3rdParty.dll.config.

Of course, tool should be clever enough to analyze existing bindingRedirect-s and find that correct redirect is already in config file.

Comment: MSBuild already knows how to do that, why you don't see it is hard to guess.  Did you even try it?

Comment: If you are talking about MSBuild warnings "consider adding binding redirect..." then I don't get them. I guess the issue is with 3rd party components referring other 3rd party components...